# C# Conversion from List<List<int>> to IList<IList<int>>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, generics

I have a C# function like this-

```
public IList<IList<int>> Subsets(int[] nums)
{
    List<List<int>> output = new List<List<int>>();
    if (nums.Length == 0)
    {
        return output;    //Problem in this line
        //return null;
    }
    ........
    ........
    return output.Concat(Subsets(nums.Skip(1).ToArray())).ToList();
}
```

What I am finding is-

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

Error   CS0266
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<int>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<System.Collections.Generic.IList<int>>'.

An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) LeetCode    D:\LeetCode\Solution.cs 13  Active
```

[image: Error]

Can anyone please help?

Comment: What if you change the initialization to `new List<IList<int>>()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@NetMage](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2557128/netmage) for the great comment.

I have changed

```
return new List<List<int>>();
```

to

```
return new List<IList<int>>();
```

Which works great for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
IList<IList<int>> list2 = list.Cast<IList<int>>().ToList();
```

You have to add `using System.Linq;` for that.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
List<List<int>> output = new List<List<int>>();
```

to

```
List<IList<int>> output = new List<IList<int>>();
```

You can cast the outer list to IList, since List implements IList, but you can't force the cast of the type argument of List, so it should be declared as IList since the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Though, I agree with other answers to create appropriate interface, you **can do this** without creating new list like *Gur Galler* proposed with a little bit of hardcore hacking:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct Union
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public List<List<int>> a;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public IList<IList<int>> b;

    public static IList<IList<int>> Cast(List<List<int>> list)
    {
        var u = new Union();
        u.a = list;
        return u.b;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var lists = new List<List<int>>() { new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 } };
        IList<IList<int>> casted = Union.Cast(lists);
    }
}
```